# TinyMCE just moves text outside of a <a> tag

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

I have perfectly valid links.

[image]

And TinyMCE transforms it to:

[image]

Why?
[Fiddle here.](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/uZfaab/11)

Comment: Can you make a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows this happening?  Seeing running code will help people identify the issue.

Comment: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/uZfaab/11

Comment: What you are making is what TinyMCE calls a bookmark/anchor (no `href`).  It will move the text outside the a tag.  I could give you a mind-numbing amount of detail as to why it does that but you won't be able to stop it from doing that when there is no `href` on the tag.

Comment: Thanks. Adding href attribute helps.  Is it documented somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is in the Michael's comment. Anchor needs to have a href attribute.